# Are there any features like Winamp's auto tag exist for iTunes?

Tags: macos, itunes, software-recommendation, music, id3-tag

It took me 3 months to ID3 Tag all of the MP3s (artist, album, released year, etc) in my iTunes library.  It was annoying.  I saw that Winamp solves this problem with an "Auto Tag" feature.  Is there a plugin for iTunes on OS X to do the same? Or does iTunes itself support this?

### P.S: I would like the program or plugin or whatever else to be compatible with iTunes.

Comment: Apple makes stuff that works with Windows, you know. Some stuff also works under Linux. Still apple, just no OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many search I find [TuneUp](http://www.tuneupmedia.com/index.php?gclid=CLOG9O6ugKQCFVMB4wodwXfkHA) it's done what I want.

TuneUp is an easy-to-use and powerful plug-in for iTunes & Windows Media Player, and also available for both Mac and windows.

Answer (score 8):

[MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Picard_Tagger) works quite well, it uses the same database as iEatBrainz but is still actively developed.  It's free, and I've had great luck with it fixing tags on some 40GB of music I had laying around from my Windows days.

The interface is somewhat arcane unfortunately.  Check out [this link](http://alternativeto.net/desktop/musicbrainz-picard/) that will give you some other alternative ideas.

on edit:
I went back to check out the newer version of Picard (0.12 vs 0.11), and the workflow is much improved.  A lot of the annoying things from before have been automated.  If you take a few minutes to set all the preferences to your tastes using the online help as reference, this really is a great automated tagging app.

Answer (score 3):

iTunes does have a "Get Track Names" option under the "Advanced" menu. That should be what you're looking for. Granted it might not find *everything*, but it finds most of them.

[image]

If you aren't ripping from a CD, then I suggest [iEatBrainz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEatBrainz), though you will have to scrum up a UB for it.

Other software:

- [Jaikoz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaikoz) (Java)
- [MusicBrainz Picard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MusicBrainz_Picard) (Python)
- [iEatBrainZ UB](http://6v8.gamboni.org/IEatBrainz-Universal-Build.html)

Comment: this option just work when you RIP the CD but when you download MP3 this option doesn't work. then it's not a proper answer for me:(

Comment: @Am1rr: Ah, I thought these were from CD. Second option: [iEatBrainz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEatBrainz), though that comes with issues like not having an "official" UB.

Comment: +1 for your answer and if can't find better one I accept this in future.

Comment: I must add some note about your answer:
1-iEastBraind was not supprted in futur and developer leave the project but maybe in future they put the source of code in sourceforge.
2-Jaikoz was not free :(
3- except iEatBrainz other application you suggest was not compatible and work with iTunes :(

Answer (score 2):

There's also an application called [SongGenie](http://www.equinux.com/us/products/songgenie/index.html). It looks very good, too.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [TidySongs](http://www.tidysongs.com/). From their website :

*TidySongs is an easy and powerful program that will fix any missing or misspelled song details, add album artwork, remove duplicate songs and organize your music.*

Answer (score 0):

[MetaBliss](http://metabliss.com/) is good, but costs $20

You are limited to working with batches of 5000 at a time, but the bulk update feature is great