# Real alternative to Tag&Rename

Tags: software-recommendation, music, id3-tag

I was using [Tag&Rename](http://www.softpointer.com/tr.htm) (an MP3 tag editor) on Windows and I'm looking for a real alternative for OS X.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any features like winamp auto tag exists for iTunes?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286/is-there-any-features-like-winamp-auto-tag-exists-for-itunes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jaikoz](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/18360/jaikoz-audio-tagger) and [Music Man](http://www.mireth.com/pub/mpme.html) can do it for you.

you can also use some free apps too:

1. [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/)
2. [ID3 Editor](http://www.pa-software.com/products/overview.php?prod=BC3B2E3A)

Answer (score 2):

[The tagger](http://deadbeatsw.com/thetagger/)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no tagging software on OS X as polished and features complete as Tag&Rename.

Beside the ones aforementioned, I use [SimpleTagger](http://code.google.com/p/simpletagger/) which enables you to tag from Amazon (including cover) and rename your files from tags.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly use `mid3v2`. Some examples:

```
mid3v2 --artist Artist --title Title --album Album --track 1 file.mp3
for f in *.mp3;do a=${f%% - *};t=${f#* - };t=${t%.mp3};mid3v2 --artist "$a" --title "$t" "$f";done
mid3v2 -l file.mp3 # list tags
mid3v2 -l file.mp3|sed -n s/^TPE1=//p # artist
mid3v2 -D file.mp3 # delete all tags
for f in *.mp3;do l=$(mid3v2 -l "$f");mv "$f" "$(printf %02d $(sed -n 's,^TRCK=0*\([^/]*\).*,\1,p'<<<"$l")) $(sed -n 's,^TIT2=,,p'<<<"$l"|tr '/:?<>\\*|"^' _).mp3";done
mid3v2 --delete-frames $(mid3v2 -l *|LC_ALL=C sed -n 's,^\([^=]*\)=.*,\1,p'|sort -u|grep -Exv 'TPE1|TIT|TALB|TRCK|TYER|TDRC'|tr \\n ,) * # keep only specified tags
```

You can install `mid3v2` by running `sudo easy_install pip;sudo pip install mutagen`. `id3v2` and `id3tag` don't support Unicode and `id3tool` doesn't support ID3v2.

Answer (score 0):

Tag & Rename works on PlayOnMac.
PlayOnMac is a Windows compatibility layer (but it's not a virtual machine). It's free and you don't need a Windows license either. First, you need to download and install PlayOnMac, then buy Tag & Rename and install it from within PlayOnMac.
After that, it just works like a usual app.