# Alternative to iTunes Album Art

Tags: itunes, software-recommendation, desktop, lyrics

I'm looking for an alternative to iTunes' Album Art. I liked it so far but since the upgrade to Lion / latest iTunes I see some annoying bugs.

To be worth considering, the alternative I'm looking for *must have* at least these three features:

- Automatic lyrics download and saving in the ID3 tag;
- Automatic cover download (iTunes is confused when the album title is missing);
- Display cover/title/artist on the desktop.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As for "Display cover/title/artist on the desktop." are you looking for something that changes the desktop background to match the album artwork of the currently playing song?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5614/1346

Comment: Really!? You dug up the topic for that?

Answer (score 1):

For the lyrics part, I would recommend [Get Lyrical](http://shullian.com/get_lyrical.php). It can actively tag songs, tag specific songs, or tag a playlist. It gets all of its lyrics from [Lyrics Wiki](http://lyrics.wikia.com/Lyrics_Wiki). This is a great little application and I highly recommend it. It has a simple, clean interface that is really easy to use:

[image: Get Lyrical]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Corripio Artwork Finder](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/21050/corripio-artwork-finder) or [Album Art Thingy](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/22542/album-art-thingy) ?  They do cover art and lyrics.

Answer (score 0):

There is [www.itunescovers.com](http://www.itunescovers.com/), export your iTunes library as XML file and upload it there, they find almost every CD cover available!

Answer (score 0):

**Tagalicious** is a paid for app that:

- Works seeminglessly with iTunes.
- Finds Album Art & Song Lyrics
- Organises your music with the right information & tags

It maybe expensive, but it may also be worth it where other apps have let you down in the past.

More info:

http://thelittleappfactory.com/tagalicious/