# What tool do I best use to automatically cleanup / correct / complement the song info of all songs in my iTunes library?

Tags: itunes, software-recommendation, music, id3-tag, metadata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any features like winamp auto tag exists for iTunes?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286/is-there-any-features-like-winamp-auto-tag-exists-for-itunes)

Please suggest both mac and windows tools.
Please also tell us about your experience with this tool.

Answer (score 1):

I find that dropping my music files onto [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org) almost always finds the correct name and fills out missing or incorrect information. It has a slightly steeper learning curve than some of the alternatives but the results are, in my experience, usually better.