# Is there free software for recognizing a song when it plays?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, software, music

I have few .mp3 file that have no name or have a wrong name(artist name and song name) is there any free software exist to recognized what exactly this song is(by playing the song and this software search their database and find similar signal wave)?

I see some similar app in iphone (if you play song and run this app after some second this app recognize the song)

And I Also use [Tunatic](http://www.wildbits.com/tunatic/) in windows and it was a good software but I can't use [Tunatic](http://www.wildbits.com/tunatic/) in OS X ([Tunatic](http://www.wildbits.com/tunatic/) is available for MAC OS X too)

I know some software exist to tag music like TuneUP and MusicBrainz and ... but I want some thing else. [I don't want answer like this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286/is-there-any-features-like-winamp-auto-tag-exists-for-itunes).

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want TuneUP or MusicBrainz? How about why you can't use Tunatic?

Comment: @ben if I want to answer simply because work with software like Tunatic is very easier than work with software like musicBrainz and ... .

Comment: if it's only a few songs that are unknown could you just use MusicBrainz for those and TuneUp or something else for the rest?

Comment: You might have to accept the fact that there is no such application @Am1rr3zA

Comment: @Ivo I myself find Tunatic that do what I meant exactly but it has problem on my notebood so I want equivalent of Tunatic

Comment: I believe that you already know it (from what I see) but TuneUP clearly: “digitally "listens" to your music to identify it”. It’s a software that you install in your mac, that can listen to the sone. Tunatic too. What else do you need?

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if you have a smartphone, but [Shazam](http://www.shazam.com) and [SoundHound](http://www.soundhound.com/) work well by using the phone's mic to identify songs while they're playing.  And I know you said you don't want to use MusicBrainz, but have you tried the scan feature?  It scans the song and tries to identify it based on a musical "fingerprint", not just by metadata.

Comment: this app you suggest don't useful for me, I want 3rd-party software to install on my mac not on my mobile.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't sure if a smartphone app would work for you or not.

Comment: Shazam is available for the Mac too: https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/shazam/id897118787?mt=12

Comment: Update in 2018: Apple bought Shazam, and you can now just ask Siri to identify songs!